# How to have only preferred vendor pricing appear in NS saved search results

Tags: netsuite

In a report showing sales of an item, I only want the price to appear for the preferred vendor.

Under the criteria, I am using formula(numeric)

```
case when {vendor} = {othervendor} then 1 else 0 end 
with greater than or equal to 1
```

but when I submit the search, it gives me an error:

> Your formula has an unrecognized field in it. Please go back and
>   correct the formula and resubmit.

Answer (score 1):

I had almost exactly this issue. In the filters side you can use `ispreferredvendor` (though for the result columns it's not available and you need to use a formula like the above).

Comment: Just figured it out. Since its a transaction search I needed to use the item join, so item.vendor. Thanks!